# How to bind count properties to TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, binding, count

I'm wondering if it's possible to bind a `List.Count` to `TextBlock`?

All this while I will store `List.Count` into a variable and bind the variable to textBlock

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding [someViewModel].manualAssignCountVariable}/>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to bind a `List.Count` straight to XAML? Maybe something like below:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding [someViewModel].someList.Count()}/>
```

Or please suggest what is the most efficient way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <TextBlock Text={Binding [someViewModel].someList.Count,Mode=OneWay }/>
```

Comment: I've tried. It's throwing error about Mode. So your way need to specify `Mode=OneWay` in order to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `IValueConverter`. You can bind the `List` and then just return `List.Count` Method in the Converter. Read more about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)